# javascript add event listener not working with angularjs $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my html file:

```
<section data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{name}}
    <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
</section>
```

this is my controller:

```
angular.module('users').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.name="HELLO";

        document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",function(){
            $scope.name="changed";
        });
}]);
```

the html file displays HELLO but it does not changes to "changed" on clicking the button.
i am new to angular can someone please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because regular event listeners don't trigger a `$digest` cycle within Angular, which is what will update the view. You *should* be using `ngClick` and defining a `$scope` function:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function() { $scope.name = "changed"; };
```

And the HTML:

```
<button ng-click="clickHandler()">Button1</button>
```

Comment: Addition: another way of solving this (because you will encounter third party code / libraries with which this solution cannot be applied) is by calling `$scope.$apply();` after a variable in the `$scope` was updated.